# Typo3 Extension Scheduler Command Controller

Tags: command, typo3, task, scheduler

here is a problem I encountered in TYPO3 Extension Development.

I've written an TYPO3-extension. It will display in browser the news in the DB. But I'd like to configure a scheduler task to recurrently update the news in the DB to be displayed.

In writing this scheduler task I've used a Command Controller.

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Command;

class CheckNewsCommandController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\CommandController
{
    public function simpleCommand()
    {
        $newsRepository = $this->objectManager->get( \Vendor\Extension\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository::class );
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($newsRepository);

        $all_news = $newsRepository->findAll();
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($all_news);
    }
}
```

But the variable **$all_news** contains nothing, it equals to **NULL** !!! That means, the **findAll()** Function of the **NewsRepository** does NOT work at all !!!

In comparison, I've also used this **NewsRepository** in a normal Controller Class: **Vendor\Extension\Controller\NewsController**

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Controller;

class NewsController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{
    public function listAction()
    {
        $newsRepository = $this->objectManager->get( \Etagen\EtSocNewsSt\Domain\Repository\NewsRepository::class );

        $all_news = $newsRepository->findAll();
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($all_news);
    }
```

And, in the *NewsController*, the function *NewsRepository::findAll()* DID really work, and returned all records in the DB.

So, who can tell me, why the Repository function will **ONLY** work in the class **Vendor\Extension\Controller\NewsController**, but **NOT** work in the class **Vendor\Extension\Command\CheckNewsCommandController** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **EASY**: You need to define the storagePid for your news records in the CommandController **OR** change the settings of the NewsRepository to **IGNORE** the storagePid.

How to set the storagePid for CommandController:
https://worksonmymachine.org/blog/commandcontroller-and-storagepid

How to set the repository to ignore storagePid:
http://typo3.sascha-ende.de/docs/development/database/how-to-ignore-the-page-id-pid-in-repository-database-query/